# How to figure out where a link gets redirected

Tags: shell-script, wget, curl, http

I currently working on a script that updates a file. The file has several versions. The important ones have static links. These get redirected to the actual file which then gets downloaded using `wget`. I have figured out that `wget` has a flag whcih prints the headers recived. There is a list of Locations. The last location meantoned in the header is the actual URL. I need to get that!

My idea was to use `wget -S` to get the header (I need another flag that prevents the file from downloading and creating). Then use a pipe to parse the lines and catch the last line containing `location`. I guess this could be realized by using `grep -l -i "location:" | tail -l`. Then I should be left with a single line that can be easily parsed.

So the command would look something like this:

```
# The -??? flag is the one that prevents the file from downloading. (I don't know it)
Location=$(wget -S -??? $URL | grep -l -i "location:" | tail -l)
```

My question what flag do I have to use to not download the file with `wget` or is there another way/command to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is a HEAD request, but `wget` does not support it; `curl` does.

Your distribution most probably has `curl` in repositories.

`curl -s -I $URL -L | awk '/Location: (.*)/ {print $2}' | tail -n 1`

```
$ URL=http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89282/
$ curl -s -I $URL | awk '/Location: (.*)/ {print $2}' | tail -n 1
/questions/89282/how-to-figure-out-where-a-link-gets-redirected
$ _
```

Here:

- `-s` prevents `curl` from showing a progress bar;
- `-I` makes `curl` issue a HEAD request;
- `-L` makes `curl` follow redirects (thanks @brianstone), you may want or not want to include this, depending on which redirect headers you want to track;
- the awk script prints the matched expression in parens, just the local part of the URI.

Comment: Ok. But if I now modified the pattern like this: `/Location: .*\/([^\/]*)\/.*/` how woul I get the what's in the brakets?

Comment: If you want to get a particular _subexpression_, try something this: `curl -s -I $URL | awk '/Location: .*/ {where=match($2, "[0-9]+"); print substr($2, where, RLENGTH)}' | tail -n 1`. In my example, it prints the `89282`.

Comment: /* Dear readers, if you want to use `-L` instead of `-I` above, please write a comment explaining the benefits of doing so. Just editing my answer is not a good idea. Thanks. */

Comment: @9000, [he did](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/89286/revisions), he added another extra line which you forgot to remove when reverting the change.

Comment: Thanks @brianstone, I'm giving you proper credit :) I still wish you did not amend my answer but added a comment below it, so we could discuss if the amendment is appropriate. See, the original post says the the tool _does not_ need to follow redirects, but instead allow to pick a certain `Location` header.

Comment: Well, I tried to express it needs to follow the redirects. And you're right. I should have asked for it instead of just editing it. I just thought you forgot the flag.

Comment: What's important is that your problem is hopefully solved by the concerted effort :)

Comment: It looks like `-I` is called twice in the example code. I assume one was meant to be `-L`? I made a few adjustments and ended up with the following: ``. You can replace 'Location' with other headers. Also FYI if you only want the final location, you can just use `curl -ILs -o /dev/null -w '%{url_effective}' URL`.